# Apply function to all elements in array<string> column

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, substring

I have a column with arrays of strings, e.g. like this:

```
["test.a" "random.ac"]
["test.41" "random.23" "test.123"]
```

I want to get only the text before the ".". I did it only for the fist element of the array. How do I do it to all elements? Preferably without UDFs.

```py
df = df.withColumn("address", substring_index(col("all_addresses").getItem(0), ".", 1)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a similar idea as @wwnde - `transform` function. `transform` takes an array, transforms every its element according to the provided function and results in the array of the same size, but with changed elements. Exactly what you need.

However, having the same original idea, I would probably implement it differently.
2 options:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(["test.a", "random.ac"],),
     (["test.41", "random.23", "test.123"],)],
    ['c1']
)

df = df.withColumn('c2', F.transform('c1', lambda x: F.element_at(F.split(x, '\.'), 1)))
df = df.withColumn('c3', F.transform('c1', lambda x: F.regexp_extract(x, r'(.+)\.', 1)))

df.show()
# +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# |                  c1|                  c2|                  c3|
# +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# | [test.a, random.ac]|      [test, random]|      [test, random]|
# |[test.41, random....|[test, random, test]|[test, random, test]|
# +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: F.transform is on available as a functionin spark 3.  If you need to use it in spark 2.x you can use `expr("transform( col, col -> col != 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp_extract. extra `alphanumerics` matches  if only followed by special character `.`

```
+---+------------------------------+
|id |text                          |
+---+------------------------------+
|1  |[test.a, random.ac]           |
|2  |[test.41, random.23, test.123]|
+---+------------------------------+



 df.withColumn('new', expr("transform(text,x->regexp_extract(x,'[a-z0-9]+(?=\.)',0))")).show()

+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|                text|                 new|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1| [test.a, random.ac]|      [test, random]|
|  2|[test.41, random....|[test, random, test]|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```